# NextJS client side components are not fully working while testing UI with playwright

Tags: playwright, next.js13

I have a NextJS (13.4) application using the App router. In one of the pages I have an `<InitialForm />` form component that allows the user to set some initial data and when the button is clicked, instead of submitting the form it opens a modal with a `<SingUpForm />` component.

`<InitialForm />`, ` and the modal are Client Side Components.

If the user set any data in `<InitialForm />` that data will be displayed in `<SignUpForm />`.

The thing is, I installed playwright for adding E2E to the application and I'm adding a test for checking the modal with `<SignUpForm />` component is rendered when the user clicks the button from `<InitialForm />`.

This is the code I have for the test, very simple:

```js
test('should display SignUpForm on button clicked', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('/');
  await page.getByTestId('open-signup-modal-button').click();
  await expect(page.getByTestId('modal-signup')).toBeVisible();
});
```

When I execute the test the button is clicked but instead of opening the modal it triggers a submit event in the form and the page is realoaded (default behaviour of a `<form>`).

I tried to add a submit handler to prevent it.

```
<form onSubmit={event => event.preventDefault()}>

</form>
```

It didn't work. I tried the same with the button, which does not make sense as it has `type="button"`:

```
<button type="button" onClick={event => event.preventDefault()}
```

It didn't work. I saw playwright has the method `page.waitForLoadState()` so I tried it passing the value `domcontentloaded` but it did nothing...So I don't know what to do to fully  test the application.

This is a basic structure of the app (omitting imports):

```
// page.jsx
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <main>
      <InitialForm />
    </main>
  );
}

// InitialForm
export default function InitialForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const [visible, toggle] = useModal();

  return (
    <form 
      name="signup"
      onSubmit={(event) => { 
        event.preventDefault(); // Does not work
      }}
    >
      <input name="name" onChange={/* setName */} />
      <input name="name" onChange={/* setEmail */} />

      <Modal
        isVisible={visible}
        hide={toggle}
      >
        <SignUpForm name={name} email={email} />
      </Modal>

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault(); // Does not work
          toggle();
        }}
      >
        Continue
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

// SignUpForm
export default function SignUpFormModal({ name, email }) {
  function handleSubmit() {
    /* submit logic */
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value={name} />
      </label>

      <label>
        Email: <input type="email" name="email" value={email} />
      </label>

      {/* more form fields */}

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Pls share the relevant html page source.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I added the base JSX

Comment: Thanks.Does it work manually as expected?

Comment: Yes, it works. Something I tried is to click as fast I can the InitialForm's button and I can reproduce the same issue I have with Playwright.
It seems in that short of period of time not all the scripts are fully loaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After further investigation I tried to run the tests usings Cypress and I found an issue with a NextJS `Script` component using `beforeActivity` strategy that cause an error on hydration.

I removed the strategy and the tests run perfect using Playwright and Cypress.